# ¿A qué se debe este error? TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript

Este es el error completo:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')
at renderHtml (index.js:28:5)
at getBlogContent (index.js:48:5)

Así es como tengo el código, la verdad no entiendo como resolverlo.

Según un error estaria en estas lineas de código:

```
const renderHtml = (user, posts) => {
    const content = document.getElementById('content');
    content.innerHTML += `<h3>Posts del usuario ${user.email}</h3>`;
```

Y en la linea del renderHtml:

```
    renderHtml(user, posts);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

getBlogContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Te esta diciendo que content no existe. Y como no existe, no puede acceder a su propiedad innerHTML.

Es decir que

```
const content = document.getElementById('content');
// Esto está devolviendo un "undefined"
```

Algo está mal ahí...
O has escrito mal "content" en el archivo html. O estás intentando acceder a él antes de tiempo. O le has puesto "class" = content en vez de "id" ... etc, por ahí van los tiros.